# Restrict one network associated with one EC2 to access second EC2 instance using common load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The question is regarding IP restriction for multiple ec2 instances running with one load balancer.

We are having two ec2 instances with public domains a.com and b.com respectively. And these two public domains are to be used from two network addresses only i.e 1.2.3.4 and 5.6.7.8 respectively.

I have whitelisted the network addresses in the Load balancer security group. But here the load balancer is common to both public domains.

Will I have to use another load balancer ? **And I think we can not create multiple load balancers listening on same https port 443. Then how can I achieve my requirement ?**

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation is unclear. When you say `a.com`, are you referring to a public DNS name that resolves to an IP address associated with an instance? What do you mean when you say "should not be able to use domain a.com" -- are you referring to the ability to resolve the DNS name, or the ability to access an EC2 instance? Why do you only have one Load Balancer if you have two separate systems for different customers? Please edit your question to provide a clearer explanation of your situation.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have edited the question description. Please check if I was able to explain it.